# Rename the same column in a list of identical data frames in r

Tags: r, loops, rename

I'm fairly new to R and I was wondering if someone could help me?

I have a list of identical data frames (df1, df2, ..., df9) and I'm trying to rename one of the columns, 'value', in all the data frames to be 'value_dataframename'- the renamed column in all 9 data frames should be value_df1 in df1, value_df2 in df2, ..., value_df9 in df9.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Would you mind sharing a code snippet of your (latest) attempt? It can be good learning, as you might actually be close to the answer and might only require a few tweaks

Comment: The only thing I've managed to do so far is repeat this bit of code 9 times with the appropriate changes, which I know isn't efficient:                                                                                                       
 200<- 200 %>%
            rename(
            Value_200 = Value
            )

Comment: If you find my answers useful, please mark them as "solved". Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code with example list (auto.list) that does what you want. Run it to check.
To use it for your list:

1. skip the code till the `your.list <- ...` line,
2. save your list as `your.list` object,
3. assign to `term` your "value".

```
auto.list <- list()

for (i in seq_len(10)) {
  auto.list[[i]] <- data.frame("a" = 1:i, "value" = sample(letters, i))
  names(auto.list)[i] <- paste0("df", i)
}
    
your.list <- auto.list # assign to your.list your own list
term <- "value" # assign your own "value"
   
for (i in seq_along(your.list)) {
  colnames(your.list[[i]])[colnames(your.list[[i]]) == term] <- paste0(term, "_", names(your.list)[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
## these two are my sample data frames for this example
df_1 <- data.frame(first = rbinom(10,size = 2,prob = 0.3), second = rnorm(10))
df_2 <- data.frame(first = rbinom(10,size = 2,prob = 0.3), second = rnorm(10))

# R stores data frames as list, so you can retrieve all your data frames thus:
all_df_names = ls.str(mode = "list")

# to check: all_df_names[1] - the first element - will give you "df_1", which is the name of the first data frame
# be careful though - 'ls.str(mode = "list")' will pick ALL the lists currently in your environment
# if you don't want to use this ls method, it might be wiser to manually create a variable 'all_df_names' and put all your data frame names there yourself.

# rename
for(i in 1:length(all_df_names)) {
  # get the actual content via its variable name, and store it in a temporary variable 'x'
  x = get(all_df_names[i])
  # rename the column you want
  names(x)[2] = paste0(names(x)[2], "_", i)   # this will replace the column with the previous name plus a '_' and the current iteration
  # resave that dataframe, with the new content
  assign(all_df_names[i], x)
}

# to remove variables we no longer need when done:
# rm(x, i)

# confirm
# names(df_1) = "first"    "second_1"
# names(df_2) = "first"    "second_2"
```

Comment: That's awesome. If it's exactly what you wanted, please mark it as the accepted answer (or perhaps upvote it at least, if you would). All the best.